# In SmartGit/Hg, how do I reference an existing mercurial repositories as a clone of another?

Tags: mercurial, clone, smartgit

I cloned a mercurial repository in MacHg, and but I prefer SmartGit/SmartHg's UI and would rather manage these in SmartHg.

I opened both the original and cloned repositories successfully in SmartHg, but I'm uanble to push/pull between them. In MacHg, it appears the way to do this is to create a document containing a repository, and then do Repository > Incoming (or Repository > Outgoing) to reference another repository as being an origin or clone, thus, enabling pushing and pulling between repositories.

How does one do this in SmartGit/Hg?

Thanks!

Comment: You *can't* do that with SmartGit/Hg currently. Instead you have to resort to manually link the repositories: stackoverflow.com/questions/4956346